# Is it safe to disable the write-protection of registers all the time in a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, safety, register

Because the hardware write-protection feature is given only for few registers while there are many other critical registers are left unprotected in a typical microcontroller (For example in [Renesas RX66 micro family](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/698/r01uh0825ej0111_rx66n-2931384.pdf)). So I feel it's not useful to have half-protection.

Shall I disable the write-protection during system initialisation itself and leave them unprotected for the rest of the code? This will simplify my register access and saves some program memory.

Comment: Write protection mostly makes sense for registers that you initialize once and then intend to never touch again. Write protecting something like a GPIO register would be senseless, because then it can't be used as output. Discussing this in general terms is probably not helpful. For certain types of applications, ie safety-related, you often guarantee the integrity of such registers by writing the default values to them from flash, cyclically.

Comment: Can you prove that your code doesn't mess with them? What happen if someone messes with these registers? These are unknown to anyone else beside you.

Comment: @Lundin, yes, in my legacy application such regiters are peridically monitored and default values are overwrittern if they are changed in order to enusre the system integirty. In such case, disabling the write-protection permanently will save some CPU and memory. For this reason I raised this question.

Comment: "in my legacy application such regiters are peridically monitored and default values are overwrittern if they are changed ... " yuk. so if something has happened that should not have happened, it gets reverted even though it might have had some weird effect before the thing that should not have happened did happen ... ? I can't tell you how much I detest this kind of "design".

Comment: @danmcb Certain types of safety-critical applications, such as cars or med-tech equipment, can't be allowed to throw an error and then lie down to die. If there are errors they must keep working as good as possible. Also the kind of error that updating registers would typically protect against are stuff like cosmic rays, meaning there's nothing to ponder, just fix the problem and move on.

Comment: @Lundin if you absolutely have to carry on working even in the event of corruption caused by cosmic rays, the correct approach would be redundancy - not point and hope.

Comment: @danmcb You'd have both. Or otherwise redundancy will only save the day until the next cosmic ray hits. (Or more likely, EMI)

Comment: it's a bit too abstract in the absence of a specific example. I take your point, and OK, there might be cases where it makes sense - but all too often when I see this kind of thing implemented it makes me shudder because it really boils down to a combination of wishful thinking and laziness on the part of the designers. In the event that such an event occurs I would want to see controlled shutdown with proper event logging and recovery, combined with redundancy, so that you get the complete system back into a known safe state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is way too broad to be answered definitively for your case (because it depends on the specific processor but also very much on your application and the consequences of malfunction) ... BUT ... in general when this kind of protection is provided it is for good reason. Often it is for some hardware configuration which should be initialised and then never again touched - and if it is altered, a complete crash might occur which would be very hard to diagnose. The best answer here is "consider the intentions of the chip designers and try to use the features they provide as intended - within the parameters of your application".